# How to fix transform origin changes in SVG when resizing in the browser

Tags: css, svg, accessibility

I have an SVG with animated paths using CSS keyframes. The issue is resizing the font size for accessibility (by using command + or command - for example on a Mac) throws off the origin of the rotating paths - circles in this case.

An example of the code can be found here - https://codepen.io/owengot/pen/XwQbqK

The CSS for the circles in question is this:

```
#circle1 {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform-origin: 200px 200px;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-animation: rotate-right 12s linear 0s infinite;
}

#circle2 {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform-origin: 200px 200px;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-animation: rotate-left 24s linear 0s infinite;
}

#circle3 {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform-origin: 200px 200px;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-animation: rotate-right 12s linear 0s infinite;
}

 #circle4 {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform-origin: 200px 200px;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-animation: rotate-left 24s linear 0s infinite;
}

#circle5 {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform-origin: 200px 200px;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-animation: rotate-right 12s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

To solve this, is there either -
a) a way to prevent the resizing of the SVG element (or any  element for that matter)?
b) a way to maintain the transform origin property relative with the viewport of the SVG?

to add to solution B) I have tried fixing the origin in percentage values, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: Try increasing or decreasing the font size of the page.. haven't tried it in many browsers, but it looks like it throws the circles off axis.

Comment: Looks like it's related to this and may be a browser issue in Safari/Firefox - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668969/css-transform-origin-changing-with-font-size